# travis ci make -std=c++14 not recognized

Tags: c++, gnu-make, travis-ci

I have the error `g++: error: unrecognized command line option ‘-std=c++14’` when building my project with travis ci using premake (https://travis-ci.org/S6066/Teal/builds/171980872)
My premake script: https://github.com/S6066/Teal/blob/master/build/premake5.lua
My travis ci file: https://github.com/S6066/Teal/blob/master/.travis.yml
Thanks for help.

Edit: g++ --version gives me 4.8.5, so the real problem is Travis won't compile with g++ 6

Comment: Did you try `-std=c++1y`? What g++ version are you using?

Comment: I can't use -std=c++1y, Premake doesn't allow me to do this, and I use GCC 6, I also tried with GCC 5

Comment: Oh, wait, g++ --version gave me 4.8.5...

Comment: It appears the c++14 standard option didn't come around [until at least 4.9](http://stackoverflow.com/q/31965413/10077).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I did these scripts for a github project and c++14 works:

This is an example of a .travis.yml:

```
sudo: required
dist: trusty
language: cpp
compiler: g++
install: export CXX="g++-5"
addons:
  apt:
    sources:
    - ubuntu-toolchain-r-test
    packages:
    - g++-5
notifications:
 email:
  on_success: never
  on_failure: always
before_install: sudo apt-get update -qq
script: make --directory "Var & ReadOnly C++"
```

And this is the associated makefile:

```
all:
    $(CXX) -std=c++14 main.cpp -I . -Os -Wall -Wextra -o Example
clean:
    rm Example*
```

Comment: Look, this is the project where I use the script:  https://github.com/illescasDaniel/Var-ReadOnly This is the travis ci output:  https://travis-ci.org/illescasDaniel/Var-ReadOnly  As you can see, the build is passing

Comment: Thanks, exporting CXX worked for me, even if g++ --version still gives me g++ 4.8.5