# configure error (c++14 is required ) while installing graph-tool in Ubuntu

Tags: python, ubuntu, gcc

I'm new to Ubuntu. I downloaded a python module `graph-tool-2.22`. After I command in `graph-tool-2.22` directory

```
./configure
```

, it causes configure error.

```
$ ./configure
....blah
....blah
checking whether g++ supports C++14 features by default... no
checking whether g++ supports C++14 features with -std=gnu++14... no
checking whether g++ supports C++14 features with -std=gnu++1y... no
configure: error: *** A compiler with support for C++14 language features is required.
```

It says that c++14 is required, however, of course I have g++ (Ubuntu 4.8.4-2ubuntu1~14.04.3) 4.8.4 in my computer. What is the problem?

Comment: Double check your g++ in the console: ```g++ -v```. Your version should work with param ```-std=gnu++1y``` [according to this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31965413/compile-c14-code-with-g).

Comment: check your gcc version, you may need to upgrade to a version superior to 4.9

Answer (score 2):

Your version of gcc does not seem to have support for C++14 that `graph-tool-2.22` need.

As mentioned in the [gcc site](https://gcc.gnu.org/projects/cxx-status.html) in section **C++14 Language Features**, full support for C++14 is in `gcc 5`, with reasonable amount of features also available `gcc 4.9`.

You might like to upgrade to `gcc 5` , perhaps by upgrading to Ubuntu 16.04. Ubuntu 14.04 is old