# How to use make with C++14 with gcc 4.8.5 on RedHat 7.5

Tags: makefile, cmake, c++14, redhat

I have gcc 4.8.5 installed on a Red Hat 7.5 machine.
I wish to compile a software package on this machine.
In order to compile this package, I need to run "make".
However, when I run this, I see the following error message "error: ‘make_unique’ is not a member of ‘std’". 
My understanding (possibly incorrect) is that this message originates from the fact that 4.8.5 uses C++11 and "make_unique" requires C++14. So I presume the way to compile this is to specify that C++14 should be used when I run "make".
How do I do this ?

I have tried to set the C++ to 14 as follows:
cmake -G "Unix Makefiles" -D CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD=14

And then I ran "make".

But this gave the same error message.

Comment: Sounds like a bug in whatever software you're trying to build.

Comment: Just to be clear, you're using `cmake` here to generate your makefiles.  You should tag this question with `cmake` not `makefile`.  But, the problem has nothing to do with `cmake` either as shown below.

Comment: ok, I have tagged accordingly, as you can surmise from my question, I am not very familiar with this area, hence my poor categorization.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using compiler that does not support C++14. As stated in the [documentation](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.8.5/gcc/Standards.html#Standards):

> GCC supports the original ISO C++ standard (1998) and contains experimental support for the second ISO C++ standard (2011).

It is no surprise, since GCC 4.8 was originally released in [2013](https://gcc.gnu.org/gcc-4.8/) so it would be weird if it implemented a standard introduced a year later.

Comment: You need GCC 5.2 (or higher) if you want C++14 support; see this question & answers: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31965413/compile-c14-code-with-g

Comment: Even more clear is the GCC docs themselves: https://gcc.gnu.org/projects/cxx-status.html#cxx14

Answer (score 0):

To use C++14 or even C++17 you can compile it with [RH Devtoolset 8](https://www.softwarecollections.org/en/scls/rhscl/devtoolset-8/). The built software would run on target OS w/o any additional effort due to the "nature" of DTS compiler: the symbols available in the OS-shipped `libstdc++` gonna be resolved dynamically, while C++11 and above gonna be linked to you executable from the specially built static `libstdc++.a` provided by DTS.